# HTML radio button is selecting multiple buttons although 'name' attribute has the same value

Tags: html, radio-button, jinja2

I googled for this, and the radio button should have the same 'name' attribute to allow only a single value to be chosen.

So I did, and It's still allowing me to choose multiple values...
I used HTML and Jinja2 templates for this, so the code might be looking a bit strange..

```
   {% if search_keyword == None: %}
        <p>Please enter your search keyword</p>
    {% else: %}
        {% for i in range(0, 10) %}
        <form method="POST" action="./search">
          <h2>
              <input type="radio" name="selected_food" id="{{ i }}" value="{{ search_data["hits"][i]['recipe']['label'] }}">
              {{ search_data["hits"][i]['recipe']['label'] }}
          </h2>
          <h4>
              Calroies: {{ '%0.2f'| format(search_data["hits"][i]['recipe']['calories']) }} kcal
          </h4>
              {% for j in range(0, 40) %}
                <p>{{ search_data['hits'][i]['recipe']['ingredientLines'][j] }}</p>
              {% endfor %}
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: there is only one radio in the above code. Where are others?

Comment: What's the actual html source getting generated in the browser? Please post that as well.

Comment: @Dalvik Ahhh sorry! it's within a for loop.. I used Jinja template for this. I just updated the code..!

Comment: @RaviKThapliyal sorry for that..! just updated the code..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the above code the loop is creating multiple forms. This is the reason why you're able to select multiple values in radio.

If you can modify your code like this, it will work

```
{% if search_keyword == None: %}
        <p>Please enter your search keyword</p>
    {% else: %}
        <form method="POST" action="./search">
             {% for i in range(0, 10) %}
                <div>
                   <h2>
                       <input type="radio" name="selected_food" id="{{ i }}" value="{{ search_data["hits"][i]['recipe']['label'] }}">
                     {{ search_data["hits"][i]['recipe']['label'] }}
                   </h2>
                   <h4>
              Calroies: {{ '%0.2f'| format(search_data["hits"][i]['recipe']['calories']) }} kcal
                   </h4>
              {% for j in range(0, 40) %}
                <p>{{ search_data['hits'][i]['recipe']['ingredientLines'][j] }}</p>
              {% endfor %}

           </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </form>
     
    {% endif %}
```